# ReportTelerik set data source programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, telerik, telerik-reporting

Hello i trying to set values to my ReportTelerik programmatically with out link to database i building a DataSet with data that i need and set it to my DataSource.But it is not working i can set the values that i have in my build DataSet.

here i build my dataset

```
static DataSet GetAllData()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Product");
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ProductNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Product", typeof(string)));

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = "Vova";
    dr["Name"] = "Dany";
    dr["Name"] = "loopy";
    dr["ProductNumber"] = "1";
    dr["ProductNumber"] = "2";
    dr["ProductNumber"] = "3";
    dr["Product"] = "Car";
    dr["Product"] = "Dor";
    dr["Product"] = "Injector";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    return ds;

}
```

here i set the data

```
  var objectDataSource = new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource();
  objectDataSource.DataSource = GetAllData();
  ReportTelerik report = new ReportTelerik();
  report.DataSource = objectDataSource;
```

my ReportTelerik class(not full)

```
partial class ReportTelerik
    {


        #region Component Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for telerik Reporting designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            Telerik.Reporting.Group group1 = new Telerik.Reporting.Group();
            Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleRule styleRule1 = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleRule();
            Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleRule styleRule2 = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleRule();
            Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleRule styleRule3 = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleRule();
            Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleRule styleRule4 = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.StyleRule();
            this.labelsGroupFooterSection = new Telerik.Reporting.GroupFooterSection();
            this.labelsGroupHeaderSection = new Telerik.Reporting.GroupHeaderSection();
            this.textBox1 = new Telerik.Reporting.TextBox();
            this.pageHeader = new Telerik.Reporting.PageHeaderSection();
            this.reportNameTextBox = new Telerik.Reporting.TextBox();
            this.pageFooter = new Telerik.Reporting.PageFooterSection();
            this.currentTimeTextBox = new Telerik.Reporting.TextBox();
            this.pageInfoTextBox = new Telerik.Reporting.TextBox();
            this.reportHeader = new Telerik.Reporting.ReportHeaderSection();
            this.titleTextBox = new Telerik.Reporting.TextBox();
            this.reportFooter = new Telerik.Reporting.ReportFooterSection();
            this.detail = new Telerik.Reporting.DetailSection();
            this.textBox2 = new Telerik.Reporting.TextBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).BeginInit();
            // 
            // labelsGroupFooterSection
            // 


            this.labelsGroupFooterSection.Height = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Inch(0.28125D);
            this.labelsGroupFooterSection.Name = "labelsGroupFooterSection";
            this.labelsGroupFooterSection.Style.Visible = false;
            // 
            // labelsGroupHeaderSection
            // 
            this.labelsGroupHeaderSection.Height = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Inch(0.40000000596046448D);
            this.labelsGroupHeaderSection.Items.AddRange(new Telerik.Reporting.ReportItemBase[] {
            this.textBox1});
            this.labelsGroupHeaderSection.Name = "labelsGroupHeaderSection";
            this.labelsGroupHeaderSection.PrintOnEveryPage = true;
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.PointU(Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Inch(0.02083333395421505D), Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Inch(0D));
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.SizeU(Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Inch(6.4166665077209473D), Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Inch(0.40000000596046448D));
            this.textBox1.StyleName = "PageInfo";
            // 
            // pageHeader
            // 
            this.pageHeader.Height = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Inch(0.44166669249534607D);
            this.pageHeader.Items.AddRange(new Telerik.Reporting.ReportItemBase[] {
            this.reportNameTextBox});
            this.pageHeader.Name = "pageHeader";
            // 
            // reportNameTextBox
            // 
}

}
```

What i am missing here do i need to declare some elements in the ReportTelerik class?,that i can set the values from dataset that i build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find out you need to add this

```
this.textBox1.Value="=Name";
```